# check the index jquery

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to get i without looping? like e.ThisIndex?

```
$('#userContentImages li a').live('click', function (e) {
    if (e.button != 0)
        return false;
    var objs = $('#userContentImages li a');    
    for(var i=0; i<objs.length; i++)
    {
        if($(this).get(0) == objs.get(i))
            break;
    }
    //do stuff
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var i = $('#userContentImages li a').index(this);
```

Comment: well, working code is above... -edit- i cant really paste any.